# hyperlink in grid view not populating values in another page when clicked

Tags: c#, gridview, stored-procedures, hyperlink

please help with this hyperlink thing.. i got a grid view where one of the column contains hyperlink say ViewDetails. upon clicking ViewDetails it should get navigate to another page called as Reports.aspx where the page should display the grid row value of selectd column in grid view in labels. i have used row data bound event .. im getting blank labels if i click the hyperlink . i have written stored procedure to get the row values. and im calling it through KEY.. its TaskID which is an auto generated column which is invisible. depending on the key value i need to display the row values.

here are the codes

```
           <asp:GridView ID="GrdViewMyTasks" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
           AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#0061C1" 
           BorderStyle="None" CaptionAlign="Bottom" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" 
           Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="#0061C1" 
           Height="179px" OnRowDataBound="GrdViewMyTasks_RowDataBound" 
           ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" Width="99%"  
           onselectedindexchanged="GrdViewMyTasks_SelectedIndexChanged" 
           OnRowCreated="GrdViewMyTasks_RowCreated" >

             <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskID" HeaderText="SL No" Visible="False" ReadOnly="True">
          <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
          <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
          </asp:BoundField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task Name">
          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="TaskName" runat="server"  
          Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" Height="24px" 
          Text='<%# Eval("TaskName")%>' Width="70px"></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White" />
          <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Due Date">
          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="DueDate" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" 
          Height="20px" Width="70px" Text='<%# Eval("DueDate","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>' DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White" />
          <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Description" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" Height="20px" Width="90px" Text='<%# Eval("Description")%>'></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White" />
          <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assign By">
          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="AssignBy" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" Height="20px" Width="90px" Text='<%# Eval("AssignBy")%>'></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White" />
          <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Status" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" Height="20px" Width="90px" Text='<%# Eval("Status")%>'></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White" />
          <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="% Complete">
          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="PercentageComplete" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" Height="20px" Width="50px" Text='<%# Eval("PercentageComplete")%>'></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White" />
          <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Details">
          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink ID="ViewDetails" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" Height="24px" Width="70px" ForeColor="#0061C1" Text="ViewDetails" NavigateUrl="Reports.aspx">View</asp:HyperLink>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White" />
          <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>
```

aspx.cs code

```
    protected void GrdViewMyTasks_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink ViewDetails = e.Row.FindControl("ViewDetails") as HyperLink;
            ViewDetails.NavigateUrl = "Reports.aspx?TaskID=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        }
    }
```

code in reports.aspx.cs

```
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        MTMSService obj = new MTMSService();
        DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
        {
            MTMSDTO objc = new MTMSDTO();
            {

                //objc.TaskID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["TaskID"]);//
                DataSet rep = obj.GetReports();
                DataView Rprts = new DataView();
                Rprts.Table = rep.Tables[0];

                var table = rep.Tables[0];

                if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    LblTaskID.Text = rep.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TaskID"].ToString();
                    LblTaskName.Text = rep.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TaskName"].ToString();
                    LblDueDate.Text = rep.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DueDate"].ToString();
                    LblDescription.Text = rep.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
                    LblAssignBy.Text = rep.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AssignBy"].ToString();
                    LblStatus.Text = rep.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Status"].ToString();
                    LblPercentageComplete.Text = rep.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PercentageComplete"].ToString();
                }

                else
                {

                }


                LblTaskName.Visible = true;
                LblAssignBy.Visible = true;
                LblDescription.Visible = true;
                LblDueDate.Visible = true;
                LblStatus.Visible = true;
                LblPercentageComplete.Visible = true;
                LblAssignTo.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my stored procedure

```
        ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetReports]

        @TaskID int

        AS

        Select TaskName, DueDate, Description, AssignBy, Status, PercentageComplete, TaskID

        From dbo.Task

        Where TaskID = @TaskID;
```

please let me know where im goin wrong. im unable to get the perfect solution for this from past 1 week... its getting headache thing ..

getting error "input string is not in correct format" at commented line of reports.cs file

Comment: Make sure when you're navigating to the Url, the Url have value in query string. if not then debug "e.Row.Cells[0].Text" whether this is giving you correct Id.

Comment: yeah .. it is giving the correct ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're querying the database with Session["TaskId"] and you're showing task id on UI from query string. Are you sure that both are same?

I think you might want to use taks id from query string rather than session.

```
 objc.TaskID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["TaskID"]);
```

**Update -**

Filter the table based on your query string

```
rep.Tables[0].Select(string.Format("TaskID={0}", Request.QueryString["TaskID"]));
```

Comment: i used session instead f querystring and thn i changed my hyperlink code as ( NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("TaskID","Report.aspx?TaskID={0}") %>'>) thn i got this error ("DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'TaskID'.")

Comment: im getting output in the d Reports page now but if i click on 2nd r 3rd task its displayng only 1st task.. plz help me... 

prblm is wid my code behind in reports.aspx.cs... i have updated my thread please go through wid it...

Comment: Why you're not using Query string value instead of Session? Try it once It must work.

Comment: i tried but it wasnt wrkin... nehw im getting values nw but i guesss thrs prblm wid count part.. please go through it i hav updated my post nw

Comment: You're getting result same on every request because you're binding all records to rep.Tables[0]. You're not filtering the table records based on query string.

Comment: okie... im gettting this error if im using the the above mentioned line by u ^ (Input string was not in a correct format.)

Comment: Did you check your query string  if it contains a valid integer value?

Comment: It should be integer (represented as string) as your TaskID field is integer in your datatable.

Comment: Everything look fine for me. Can't help here by creating long chat comments. You should take another look at the Report.cs file if you're getting correct values in the Query string then It should work.

Comment: i checked it sir... but getting same error... evrythng is fine... bt dnt no wats getting wrng

Comment: thnks everybdy ... i gt d solution... was missing taskid column name in my SP of grid view